# Eclipse kepler not working due to some jvm inssue

Tags: eclipse, jvm

When I try to open eclipse it is giving this jvm error. I think, I have accidentally changed java environment variables and now eclipse is unable to find where jvm is.

Comment: Details matter. *What is the error message?*

Comment: What is the error?